# Embedded Jetty for Unit Testing

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jersey, embedded-jetty

I want to start up my application within my test class to test it. I've written a base class for my tests and have a method such like that:

```
public static void startServerIfRequired() {
   if (server != null) {
      return;
   }
   server = new Server(TEST_PORT);
   ServletHolder sh = new ServletHolder(ServletContainer.class);

   sh.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass", "com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig");
   sh.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "org.gogo.rena.rest");
   sh.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
   ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
   context.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp");
   context.setContextPath("/");
   context.addServlet(sh, "/*");

   server.setHandler(context);
   try {
      server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
      server.start();
     //server.join(); 
   } catch (Exception e) {
     fail("Error has occurred while starting! Error is as follows: " + e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

I do not have any resources at test package. I use Jersey at my Spring application. My rest packages are under gogo.rena.rest. Server does not throws error but when I try to get any URL I get 404 error?

**EDIT:** When I check the logs it says that:

```
...
Server - Started @20756ms
```

and also it founds my rest class as a root resource.

Comment: Are you seeing any relevant DEBUG or INFO messages when Jetty is starting up?

Comment: @geoand I've edited my question. Jetty starts correctly. I have a servlet mapping at webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml.

Comment: provide more detail info to check where have bug,such as the log,and your configuration, etc.

Comment: There is not much log files. On the other hand I'm not sure the configuration of application-context-test.xml (within test resources) and web.xml (within WEB-INF not test) for embedded jetty.